# Show list view in a popup window - Android

Tags: android, listview, popupwindow

I'm working on a project in Android and I have a problem.
I have an activity which includes three buttons, edit text and a list view.

[image]

I want to change that implementation and to show the list view on a new popup window only when the user press the select all button.
I've added my code, thanks.

```
public class Notepadv1 extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private WordsDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Button selectAllButton;
        private PopupWindow mPopup;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        selectAllButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
        selectAllButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        mDbHelper = new WordsDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case(R.id.selectAll):
                selectAll();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void selectAll(){
    }

    private void fillData() {

        Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] from = new String[] { WordsDbAdapter.KEY_WORD };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };


        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.words_row, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

**1st way:**
define an activity as Dialog with the below attribute in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

**2nd way:**
You can inflate the XML layout inside the dialog as below:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
LayoutInflater li = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = li.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, false);
dialog.setContentView(v);
dialog.show();
```

**for example:**

edit: link fixed

[Android Dialog with ListView](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/21/android-dialog-with-listview/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Another question, do I need to Separate it to two activities, one for the button, edit text etc., and one for the dialog?

Comment: Yes if you want to go with Activity as a dialog then you can define 2 separate activities, and if you just want to go with 2nd way mentioned above then another activity is not needed.

Comment: @OfirAN check example link mentioned above.

Comment: its workes but it also show some space,like title bar .so how can i remove this space

Answer (score 17):

Show a simple Alert Dialog with a list:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If using a custom ArrayAdapter, use [`setAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Dialog Title")
    .setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(context, items, ...), (dialog, itemPosition) -> {
      // Handle item click
    });
builder.show();
```