# Saving text data in android app as numerous listviews

Tags: android, saving-data

I want to save some text data entered by the user as listviews..but still have no idea how to do that..please help!

Comment: be specific before posting any question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465506/show-list-view-in-a-popup-window-android

Comment: Thanks @Bhavin thanks a lot! That's what I wanted! You,sir, are a diety to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, couple of ways to do that.

1. Save data as raw text into a file 
   http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html
2. Create data objects and serialize them into a binary file.
3. Store data into database (might be the best option, depends on what you are trying to do).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

can you explain more what your application does, then there might be a accurate solution to your confusion. Also try posting some code, that'll convince people that you have done some work and stuck into unknown territory.

Comment: I am developing a note making app, it gets some text data entered by the user and saves that in the form of listviews...